# The value obtained from the database is not applied to the variable

Tags: flutter, sqlite

I have a function to get a value from a sqlite database. How do I set this value to a variable?

Get value from DB

```
  getPref(Setting setting) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    try {
      dbClient.query('settings',
          where: 'name = ?',
          whereArgs: [setting.name],
          columns: ['value']).then((data) {

        List<Map<String, dynamic>> s = data;
        List<String> list = [];
        for (var x in s) {
          x.forEach((k, v) => list.add(v));
        }
        print("NAME: ${setting.name} VALUE: ${list[0]}");
        return list[0];
      });
    } on Exception catch (ex) {
      print(ex.toString());
    }
  }
```

Result:
 `NAME: mainPage VALUE: all`

But when I put this value it doesn't apply, it throws null.

```
  String page = "";
  getPage() {
    DBHelper database = DBHelper();
    database.getPref(Setting(name: 'mainPage')).then((val) {
      setState(() {
        print("VAL " + val.toString());
        page = val;
      });
    });
  }
```

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
getPref(Setting setting) async {
var dbClient = await db;
try {
  dbClient.query('settings',
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [setting.name],
      columns: ['value']).then((data) {

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> s = data;
    List<String> list = [];
    for (var x in s) {
      x.forEach((k, v) => list.add(v));
    }
    print("NAME: ${setting.name} VALUE: ${list[0]}");
    return list[0];
  });
}
```

with:

```
getPref(Setting setting) async {
var dbClient = await db;
try {
  var data = await dbClient.query('settings',
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [setting.name],
      columns: ['value']);
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> s = data;
    List<String> list = [];
    for (var x in s) {
      x.forEach((k, v) => list.add(v));
    }
    print("NAME: ${setting.name} VALUE: ${list[0]}");
    return list[0];
}
```

**What's wrong?**

When querying your db you are not waiting to complete the query before returning the `list[0]`. In other words, you are returning your `list[]` before getting the data from the database as `.then` doesn't block the execution onwards and prematurely executes `return list[0]` which you don't want.